Generate ngx_stream_geoip2_module-debug.so file from Nginx source
How can I generate ngx_stream_geoip2_module-debug.so file from nginx source? I have tried --with-debug option of configure but it doesnn't seem to be working.
Repo used: https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module

I have tried --with-debug option but it doesn't give file ngx_stream_geoip2_module-debug.so.

Clone the Nginx source and the ngx_http_geoip2_module. Run
./configure --with-debug --add-dynamic-module=ngx_http_geoip2_module

then make modules. The .so file will be in the objs directory

I have tried --with-debug option but it doesn't give file ngx_stream_geoip2_module-debug.so.
